# Magento: PayPal Checkout quantity shows as x1

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have several currencies in my Magento store:
1. CAD (BASE Currency)
2. USD (convertion)

Problem is when you checkout using USD (converted currenc), PayPal doe not show the original quantity ordered (let say quantity of 5). It only shows "Product Name- x 1" and Total price in USD$. It was mentioned in other thread that it's due to how magento rounds prices.
**Two examples**

**Example1:**
Basketball ball (ordered quantity 2), each costs 10.53 USD
Paypal Checkout shows:  Basketball ball  x1   21.06 USD

**Example2:** (Works great)

Baseball Cap:              $43.74 USD

Item price: $21.87 USD

Quantity: 2

I found a threat that shows similar issue, but **no solution was posted**.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14872/magento-order-quantity-shown-in-paypal-as-x-1-with-real-quantity-in-item-name

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please help out, gentleman :)